# AWS CLI working in shell but not working in cron job

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, cron

I tried to automate some jobs through cron on EC2. However, the aws commands failed due to an error '403 Forbidden'. The codes worked fine when I ran those in the shell. I tried almost all the solutions on stack overflow but none of those solved the issue.

The testing code is simple enough. (test copying a file from S3 to my EC2)

```
/2 * * * * /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp s3://fraud-training-test/FraudAWS_v1.R /home/ubuntu
```

Anyone has a sense of what else I could be doing to solve this issue? Thanks!

So far, I tried the following solutions:

1. Installed and configured awscli for both root and my current user;
2. Put the global path and home on top of my script

eg:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

PATH=/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin
```

3. Tried scheduling the cron job as my current user and as root but both failed.

## Below is the exact error I got from the log:

```
Subject: /usr/local/bin/aws s3 cp s3://fraud-training-test/FraudAWS_v1.R /r$
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit
X-Cron-Env: <PATH=/usr/bin:/usr/local/bin>
X-Cron-Env: <SHELL=/bin/sh>
X-Cron-Env: <HOME=/root>
X-Cron-Env: <LOGNAME=root>

fatal error: An error occurred (403) when calling the HeadObject operation: Forbidden
```

Comment: It would appear related to the AWS credentials that are being used. Does the EC2 have an assigned role that has permission to access the S3 bucket? Or are you intentionally using credentials stored in a local `~.aws/credentials` file?

Comment: I configured and gave the permission to access the S3 bucket for both the ubuntu user and the root user. And I checked the ~.aws/credentials file and the credentials look right to me in that file.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is probably that the user you configure in crontab is not the same user configured in the AWS CLI.

You must match the user that executes crontab -e with the user that is configured in aws configure

This worked fine on my Lightsail Bitnami instance.

Answer (score 0):

Check your AWS Installed Path by using `which aws` and do `ls -la` to know the user permissions.

Then run it accordingly in either `crontab -e` for current user or `sudo crontab -e` for root user.

It worked for me in Ubuntu 16.04.